# TCP connected/disconnected

Tags: c#, connection, ping, tcpclient, tcpserver

I need help with getting newtork status of my device. Firstly I need to detect on the server if the device is disconnected for example the ethernet is unplugged. Secondly, I need the same on the device side.

I tried to use classical pinging mechanism, but it doesn't work if firewall locks outgoing and incomming pings. I thought about cyclic sending frames on another tcp port and checking response timeout but I want something more safe and clear.

Any suggestions?

C#.

In my project I'm using Eneter Messaging Framwerok. All works good, connenction, messaging. The problem occurs, when after successfully connection between device and server, I will go to device and unplug ethernet cable. The server needs about 20s to detect if the device is disconnected (you can try it sending ping via command line and unplug ethernet cable from destination device). When I manually dispose connection on the device, server detects the status immediately (device-Eneter sends "close" frame to server).

Comment: Detecting layer 0 "dirty disconnect" on a "quiet" connection can only be done by making it not quiet. That means if you do not have traffic for x time, send a "dummy" and on the other end, if a "dummy" is received, send an acknowledging message. If the line is physically broken, this will fail with an exception.

Comment: Since you are using a messaging framework: it seems to have a watchdog "onboard". Maybe you just need to adjust the timeout to fit your requirement: See http://eneter.net/OnlineHelp/EneterMessagingFramework/html/94743750-5cea-45a8-bf17-f2a98655e913.htm#Reliability